# How to migrate from Custom implementation to Active Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I have a a custom implementation (made by following [this article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html))  with two tables.

The app is currently live and has data which is stored only on phone and not synced anywhere.

I am in the process of adding more features and have found that the current implementation is reducing my development speed so I thought I'd switch to ActiveAndroid.

I rewrote the code hoping that no migrations would be needed and got the app to compile. But the data isn't there. Then, when I try to add new data through app's interface, the app just stops at the `.save();` call.

There is no error thrown at this point. It just becomes unresponsive. At this point, I uninstalled the app, removing the associated data and clean installed it.

At this point, it throws an error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.reflect.Field.getType()' on a null object reference` while trying to initialize the app.

The MyApp class, which is mentioned in manifest looks like this

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
    public static Tracker tracker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ActiveAndroid.initialize(this);
        analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

        analytics.setDryRun(BuildConfig.DEBUG);

        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);

        tracker = analytics.newTracker("XXXX"); // Replace with actual tracker/property Id
        tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
        tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
    }

    public Tracker getTracker() {
        return tracker;
    }

}
```

Any idea how to move ahead with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What exception is thrown when you call `save()` method? Attach code with your models and database scheme.

Comment: There is no exception thrown. The just hangs for no reason. I uninstalled and installed the app again and now I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.reflect.Field.getType()' on a null object reference` when I try to run it.